# Creating an sqlite database search engine with python

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, cgi

I have an sqlite database with 2 tables. I need to create a cgi search engine for the database, with 2 options in a drop-down menu: Name & Keyword.

If the option is Keyword, the 1st table is searched for a matching keyword (in any column). If the option is Name, the 1st column of the 2nd table is searched for an exact match.

I have created the cgi web interface with a search box, and the drop-down menu, that saves the input search term. Now I am stuck as to how I can program my cgi script to do a search of the database based on the input term, and display the results to screen as a table.

Below are the relevant parts of my script:

```
import cgi

"""set up the content type, open the html, title, and body"""

print '<form action=search.cgi>'
print '<select name=\'dropdown\'>'
print   '<option> Name </option>'
print   '<option> Keyword </option>'
print '</select>'

print '<input type=\'text\' name=\'desc\' size=\'25\'>'
print '<button type="submit"> Go </button>'
print '</form>'

args = cgi.FieldStorage()
desc = args.getfirst("desc")
dropdown = args.getfirst("dropdown")
```

And here is where I need help:

```
if dropdown == 'Keyword':
    ...
elif dropdown == 'Name':
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to do some pretty basic sqlite database operations. The [stdlib documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) should get you most of the way. It has also links for more resources to help you do more comprehensive SQL queries.

Comment: I actually was able to retrieve results for the "Name" option, but when I do print cursor.fetchall(), the webpage only displays the text of 1 column. I want the display to include all columns in that row. This is the command I used: cursor.execute("SELECT * from GeneTab WHERE Gene LIKE ?", (query,)) \n where query is the raw input. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to perform a couple of queries, read this [SQLite Python Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm).